# Netbeans Profiler for a Maven project

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, profiling

When I try to attach a Profiler to my project, Netbeans prompts me to choose bewtween my main class and `org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher`. I was wondering if someone knows which one I should use and why.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher is the main class for the maven build. netbeans executes the maven build jvm which in turn via exec-maven-plugin starts the jvm that your main class executes in.

So if you want to profile the build you choose the classworld's Launcher, otherwise you choose your your main class.

Comment: What is the difference then to profile the build or otherwise?

Comment: each case is a different JVM :) so you either you profile your app or your maven build.